# Metrics values are equal while training and testing a model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm working on a neural network model with python using Keras with TensorFlow backend. Dataset contains two sequences with a result which can be 1 or 0 and positives to negatives ratio in dataset is 1 to 9. Model gets the two sequences as input and outputs a probability. At first my model had a Dense layer with one hidden unit and sigmoid activation function as output but then I changed my models last layer to a Dense with two hidden unit and softmax activation function and changed my dataset's result using Keras `to_categorical` function. After these changes the model metrics which contains Accuracy, Precision, Recall, F1, AUC are all equal and has a high and wrong value. Here are the implementation I used for those metrics

```
def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    precisionValue = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    recallValue = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precisionValue*recallValue)/(precisionValue+recallValue+K.epsilon()))

def auc(y_true, y_pred):
    auc = tf.metrics.auc(y_true, y_pred)[1]
    K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    return auc
```

and here is the training result

```
Epoch 1/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 17s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4511 - acc: 0.9044 - f1: 0.9044 - auc: 0.8999 - precision: 0.9044 - recall: 0.9044
Epoch 2/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4573 - acc: 0.9091 - f1: 0.9091 - auc: 0.9087 - precision: 0.9091 - recall: 0.9091
Epoch 3/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4573 - acc: 0.9091 - f1: 0.9091 - auc: 0.9083 - precision: 0.9091 - recall: 0.9091
Epoch 4/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4573 - acc: 0.9091 - f1: 0.9091 - auc: 0.9090 - precision: 0.9091 - recall: 0.9091
Epoch 5/5
4026/4026 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4573 - acc: 0.9091 - f1: 0.9091 - auc: 0.9085 - precision: 0.9091 - recall: 0.9091
```

after that I tested my model using `predict` and calculated metrics using sklearn's `precision_recall_fscore_support` function and I got the same result again. metrics are all equal and has high value (0.93) which is wrong based on the confusion matrix I generated
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure about the implementation of your recall and f1 functions? I think they are wrong.

Comment: I know that but the problem is that sklearn's `precision_recall_fscore_support` function is calculating wrong values @today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Keras 2.0 precision, Recall, F1 have been removed because these metrics are supposed to be calculated globally but they were being calculated batch-wise.Your code is similar to the one used in keras 1.X and that might be the issue.

Try using package [keras_metrics](https://pypi.org/project/keras-metrics/)

```
import keras
import keras_metrics

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", input_dim=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="sgd",
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=[keras_metrics.precision(), keras_metrics.recall()])
```